# Wix CheckBox checked condition

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I like to show a checkbox in dialog which is unchecked if the DWORD registry value is 0 or checked otherwise.

I understood the checkbox check/uncheck if the property exist or not. Is there a way to change it work with value or conditionally set or remove the property.

Checkbox is always checked as it found value in registry 0 or nonZero and set the property and this is I tried so far -

```
<Property Id="SOUNDSERVER">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SoundServer"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="[APPLICATIONHIVE]"
  Name="SoundServer"
  Type="raw"
  Win64="yes" />
</Property>

<SetProperty Id="WIXUI_SOUNDSERVER" After="AppSearch" Value="[SOUNDSERVER]" />
<SetProperty Id="WIXUI_SOUNDSERVERADDR" After="AppSearch" Value="[ACTANTSOUNDSERVERADDR]" />

<Control Id="SoundServerCheck" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="148" Width="80" Height="10" Property="WIXUI_SOUNDSERVER" CheckBoxValue="#1" Text="Sound Server">
</Control>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the condition in **SetProperty** itself. You can use the below condition in your requirement.

```
 <Property Id="SOUNDSERVER">
    <RegistrySearch Id="SoundServer"   
    Root="HKLM" 
    Key="[APPLICATIONHIVE]" 
    Name="SoundServer" 
    Type="raw" 
    Win64="yes" />
  </Property>

<Property Id="WIXUI_SOUNDSERVER" Value="1" />
<SetProperty Id="WIXUI_SOUNDSERVER" After="AppSearch" Value="{}">
    SOUNDSERVER="#0"
</SetProperty>

<Control Id="SoundServerCheck" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="148" Width="80" Height="10" Property="WIXUI_SOUNDSERVER" CheckBoxValue="#1" Text="Sound Server"></Control>
```

**Edit:**

Remove WIXUI_SOUNDSERVER property and use the SOUNDSERVER property in all places to uncheck the checkbox while registry does not exist.

```
 <SetProperty Id="SOUNDSERVER" After="AppSearch" Value="{}">
    (SOUNDSERVER="#0")
    </SetProperty>

<Control Id="SoundServerCheck" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="148" Width="80" Height="10" Property="SOUNDSERVER" CheckBoxValue="#1" Text="Sound Server"></Control>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vinoth It solve the problem of reading the DWORD and applying to checkbox. I still not able to get the box unchecked if the registry value doesn't exist at all. I tried <Property Id="WIXUI_SOUNDSERVER" Value="0" /> which doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Use <Property Id="WIXUI_SOUNDSERVER" Value="{}" /> to uncheck the Checkbox.

Comment: Solution works; I wonder can you please explain how this Value"{}" works to set default values. Many Thanks

Comment: If Checkbox property is created with any Values the Checkbox will be checked.The "{}" value delete the Property. So it is unchecked.